# About timer cancel timing

Tags: android, timer

Now, I am wondering about some situation of the Timer class of android java.
If I have activity ui with method below without cancel() method ..

```
public static void makeLooperThread(Runnable r) {
    Looper.prepare();
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(r);
    Looper.loop();
}

void myTimer() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
Utils.makeLooperThread(
        new

                Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        //.... my thread code
                    }
                });
            }, 1500);
}
```

Everytime when destroy() method is called in my activity, does the resources created on my timer thread released automatically or must i call the cancel() method explicitly?

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
public void run() {
    //.... my thread code
    timer.cancel(); //
}
```

Your answer will be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more as it is not clear what you actually willing to do.

Comment: Do i have to call cancel method in the run() method or just leave it ? Is this code any problem with the code? something like thread issues or resource leak? thanks anyway..

Comment: Is there any problem with the code? That is a part of my project source code.

Comment: final Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
public void run() {
    //.... my thread code
    timer.cancel(); //
} you cancel the just created timer but you existing timer is still there. That why I am asking what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I didn't add the cancel method in the source code at this time writing...so if no difference existing while adding or not adding the method to my code, I do need to add it but difference existed depending on some condition...I think I have to add it..I am afraid that the "some condition" exists or not..that's the question